# Compare Two Dates and If Less than TODAY Add Date till TODAY and Add 6 Months to it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have data like this in

`Column H`

```
   6-Feb-14 
   5-Oct-14 
   27-Dec-14    
   5-Feb-15 
   17-Feb-15
   2-Apr-15
```

I'm trying to add `6 months` to each date with the date being up to today. 
Like if date is `6-Feb-14` then add `6 months` to date from today. To give a detail explanation I need to work out something like this.

```
Last Paid    Next Payment Date

6-Feb-14     6-Dec-2015
```

`6-Feb-14` is last paid date > add `6-Feb-14` till today `24-June-14` and add `6 more months` to it. Resulting final date be `6-Dec-2015`.

I did try the `=EDATE()` formula and it isn't really what I'm looking for.

How do I achieve this using excel formulas?

Comment: Your question is not clear, "add till today", "then add six months", why it's different than just today + six month? Anyway the function you need is probably `EDATE()`

Comment: "Your question is not clear" — ditto.  Today is 24-June-2015, not 2014, and that plus six months is 24-Dec-2015, not 6-Dec.  What do you mean?  Try writing clearer words and adding examples to cover all the ("if") cases.  Show the formula that you tried, using the `EDATE()` function, showing what result you got and explaining why that isn't what you want.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Using `TODAY()` will continually update the date, you know? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is quite confusing, however I still get it. Try using [EOMONTH()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628) like this -

```
  (H)              (I)
  (1)  Last Paid    Next Payment Date
  (2)  6-Feb-14    =IF(H2-TODAY()<1,DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(TODAY(),6)),MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),6)),DAY(H2)),"Enter what ever you want")
```

Comment: uh, nice job bringing `EOMONTH()` out of nowhere. +1

Comment: I suspect this solution is way too overcomplicated - why the use of `TODAY` in the new date? Surely it should be 6 months from H2, not from today? Also confused about why `EOMONTH` is necessary at all... why not just pull H2's year, H2's month (+6, which will also roll-over the year when necessary) and H2's day? Thus: `=IF(H2-TODAY()<1,DATE(YEAR(H2),MONTH(H2)+6,DAY(H2),"Enter what ever you want")`
Warning: Both our solutions break when the new day doesn't exist in the updated month. i.e. August 30/31 roll over to March 1/2 rather than Feb?

Comment: @SteveTaylor: It looks like Bilo was the only person who understood this question correctly — specifically, it looks like you, DavidPostill, fixer1234, Steven, mdpc, Scott, Máté Juhász, and I did not (see above).  Refer to the example in the question: “Last Paid” (`H2`) was 6-Feb-2014, and yet the desired result was 6-Dec-2015, presumably because Dec-2015 is six months in the future (or was, when the question was posted).  So, clearly, the formula must include `TODAY()`.  But I don’t understand why `EOMONTH()` is needed; `DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+6,DAY(H2))` might be good enough.

Comment: P.S. The formula that you posted in your comment doesn’t actually work at all, because you left out a `)` (between `DAY(H2)` and `,"Enter …"`).

Comment: @G-Man: I get your point, but in that case the problem makes no sense at all, because the Next Payment Date would change every single time you open the sheet. If you always have to pay six months from 'today', then your payment date will never occur. And your solution still doesn't help where the Day of H2 doesn't exist in m+6 (ie 31st on months without a 31st)